# Python-Redmine on a project without issues

Tags: python, redmine

I have a Redmine project that is a container for subprojects. This top level project does not have issues (Issue tracking is not enabled in the project settings).

I am trying to figure out a way for the Python api to detect this. Right now, when my code (which is scanning for issue counts) is going through the projects, it gets to this one and errors out.

redminelib.exceptions.ForbiddenError: Requested resource is forbidden

What project property can I use to determine if the Issues are enabled? I tried project.issues._total_count but that always seems to evaluate to "None" for all projects (even ones with issues). I think that gets filled in later when you run an issue query. But I cannot run an issue query without failing and exiting the script.

I just want to have some logic to skip over these Issue disabled projects.

```
redmine = Redmine('https://redmine.server/redmine', key='1234567890987654321', requests={'verify': False})

projects = redmine.project.all()

for project in projects:
    issues = redmine.issue.filter(project_id=project.identifier, status_id='*')
    issueCount = 0
    for issue in issues:
        issueCount = issueCount + 1
    print( 'Project ' + project.identifier + ' has ' + str(issueCount) + ' issues' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
try:
    # code assuming issues are enabled
except redminelib.exceptions.ForbiddenError:
    # code to execute for projects where issues are disabled
```

Comment: That worked well! I would like to find a way to get the issue count without having to go through the issues resource. The query of issues can take quite a bit of time if you have a project with many issues.

Answer (score 0):

The list of enabled modules for a project can be fetched from the projects API. With your existing code, you can use e.g.

```
redmine = Redmine('https://redmine.server/redmine', key='1234567890987654321')

# Note that this returns at most 100 projects.
# You may have to use pagination to fetch any further projects
projects = redmine.project.all(include = ['enabled_modules'])

for project in projects:
  if next((module for module in project.enabled_modules if module["name"] == "issue_tracking"), None):
    continue

  # Fetch just one issue
  # the returned record set will contain the total number of issues which matched the query
  issues = redmine.issue.filter(project_id=project.identifier, status_id='*', limit=1)
  issueCount = issues.total_count
  
  print( 'Project ' + project.identifier + ' has ' + str(issueCount) + ' issues' )
  # ...
```

With this check, you can skip projects which do not have the issues module enabled.

Note however that even though the module is enabled, in a project, it might still be possible that you are not allowed to fetch any issues if you don't have the "view issues" permission in the project via a suitable role. I'm not aware of an API to verify this though, apart from trying to read issues and handling the failure.

Further along the code, you can find some improvement to your original approach of reading all issues. Here, we just read at most one issue (which we do not specifically care about). In the list however, Redmine returns the total number of issues which matches our filter which we can use here instead of having to read all issues on our own.

In any case, note that Redmine applies limits to all API responses and returns at most 100 issues/projects/users/... to a single request. If you want to fetch more you have to issues additional requests with the appropriate `limit` / `offset` arguments set. See https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Collection-resources-and-pagination for details.